# How to print a file using command prompt through a network printer

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, windows, printing

Can any one give me a idea of How to print a file using command prompt through a network shared printer....

Friendly,
Vijay.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the lpr method as long as it is enabled as a windows feature.

eg.

c:\lpr -S 192.168.1.210 -P LETTER_DUPLEX -J 123456 testfile.ps

where -S is the ip of the printer you are printing to, -P is the queue name -J is the job name you want it to be seen as and testfile.ps is the name of the file you want to print.

hope this helps